# PIL - Tkinter doesn't work for me! What I'm doing wrong

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

### First of all:

I know that here on Stackoverflow are tons of **examples** **suggestions**, **code snippets** and so on about this topic. I read most of them, tried them out **but they didn't worked for me**..

### My problem:

As soon as I launch the script It displays me a GUI in the perfect size.
But where I expect an Image there is just empty space.

### My guess:

I think I don't use the garbage collection correctly. Is this true?
If yes, what should I change?

### My question:

If the garbage collection isn't the problem, what should I edit and why?
By the way I'm using OS X Yosemite and python 2.6.

### My code:

```
import Image as Im, ImageTk
from Tkinter import *

class Simulator:

    def __init__(self):
        # Init root
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("1171x900")
        self.root.title("Cockpit Simulation")

        # Anti Garbage Collection
        self._antiGarb = None

    def backgroundImage(self):
        # Loading Image
        self._bgimage = Im.open("Image/mask.png")
        self._bgimageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self._bgimage)


        # Anti Garbage Collection
        self._antiGarb.background = self._bgimageTk


        # Background Canvas Widget
        self._backgroundCanvas = Canvas(self.root, width = 1170, height = 780)
        self._backgroundCanvas.pack()
        self._backgroundCanvas.create_image(0,0, image = self._bgimageTk, anchor = NW)


# Mainloop
main = Simulator()
main.root.mainloop()
```

### THANK YOU!!

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Err... I don't see you calling `backgroundImage()`.

Comment: Process finished with exit code 1, since I just close IDLE

Comment: what a shame. Well. I called it now. Now i get errors:                                   

line 17, in backgroundImage
    self._bgimage = Im.open("Image/mask.png")
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1952, in open
    fp = __builtin__.open(fp, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Image/mask.png'

Comment: Well, you need to check your image path then.

Comment: line 22, in backgroundImage
    self._antiGarb.background = self._bgimageTk
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'background'

Comment: well fixed this too. Now it "works" without errors. But still no Image

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected, running method (when it's actually called, see the question's comments):

```
def backgroundImage(self):
    # Loading Image
    self._bgimage = Im.open("...")
    self._bgimageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self._bgimage)

    self._backgroundCanvas = self._bgimageTk
```

You don't need the `_backgroundCanvas` attribute, just delete it in the constructor as well.

Comment: I tried exactly what you wrote above (just changed open("...") with my **correct** path. It doesn't show the picture

Comment: But what I found out:

if I just use: `self._bgimageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "Images/cockpit.gif")` it works fine. I know this time it is a gif. I just converted it and saved it. Maybe my PIL Im.open() is broken?

Comment: self._bgimage = Im.open("Image/cockpit.gif")
self._bgimageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self._bgimage)